# How can I fix an AVI file from a computer that lost power during recording?

Tags: video, avi, repair

I recorded some video on my PC using a webcam, and got an `.avi` file. My computer lost power while it was recording, so I can't view the contents of the file.

The file is about 4GB in size. The video players I tried show only a picture when they open it. The video files resulted from using "fix videos software" were similar. Extracting photos using "extract frames software" gives only five frames. Viewing the file as a binary shows (10f695f0)x lines of data each containing 32 hex values, for a total of 9,107,062,272 hex values. The video's frame rate and dimension are known.

How can I restore my video? I would be happy with a programming solution, a software package... anything that works.

Comment: Look at VLC, it can play prettymuch anything, and can write videos to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it through [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/), making use of the `-er` flag.

From the man page:

> **-er** *n*
>   Set error resilience to *n*.
>       **1**   FF_ER_CAREFUL (default)
>       **2**   FF_ER_COMPLIANT
>       **3**   FF_ER_AGGRESSIVE
>       **4**   FF_ER_VERY_AGGRESSIVE

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to play the file using Mplayer - http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html or KMPlayer - http://www.kmplayer.com (edit - sorry, didn't notice this was six years old post)

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer. Why do you think those players will play the corrupted file? Do they have special file-restore features? All that kinda stuff would be nice in your answer.